# Storing/Getting values in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as my back-end solution and I now need to store some booleans to the server and retrieve them as well.

I have created a ParseObject:

```
public ParseObject prefs = new ParseObject("Prefs");
```

and I stored it like this:

```
prefs.put("setting1", true);
```

and saved in background:

```
prefs.saveInBackground();
```

but when I try to use the bool after retrieving it simply like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Prefs");
    query.getInBackground(prefs.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                if(parseObject.getBoolean("setting1")){
                    //Do something
               } 
            } else{
                utils.toast_error("Check your internet connection");
                Gdx.app.log("PARSE", "Some "+e.getCode());
            }
        }
    });
```

it doesn't return true, instead it returns it core value false.
Have I missed a step or something? Is there more to retrieving data than what I've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are sure to use the getInBackground method to retrieve the ParseObject?

This could be useful:
https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#subclasses

Comment: Should I use getInBackground instead of just get? I've read all from that guide.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the values stored in the cloud you should use the getInBackground that will issue a network request to fetch the data. 

If I were you I will proceed in this way:  
  
1) check at https://www.parse.com under your registered app if the "Prefs" object are actually stored. This will verify that you are using the proper app tokens and the saving phase run fine   
2) If in the backend your data is stored fine, be sure to query the proper object id in your getInBackground method  
3) Try to log the ParseExceptions to find if there are any issues

Comment: I checked and it is stored. It even indicates the correct value of the bool I'm testing. It is set to true on Parse.com but when I logged the bool in app, it still is false.. So the saving is done properly. Something about my retrieving that is wrong I suspect. I simply queried it as they do in the documentation. See edit in my post. ParseException from that getInBackground is 101, no object found.

Comment: I think the point missing is that the objectId is assigned only after the saveInBackground is finished.
Try to use saveInBackground(SaveCallback <ParseObject> saveCallback) and call the getObjectId in the done method assigning it to a variable that must be used instead of prefs.getObjectId()